# Не отображается модель на странице

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

консоль не выдает ошибок, сеть показывает, что модель на сцену загрузилась, но увы не появляется
если кто знает, в чем проблема, прошу объяснить простым языком, не разбираюсь в js)

```
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0,1, 1000);
  camera.position.z = 50;
  scene.add(camera);

  renderer= new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true, antialias: true});
  renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);
  renderer.setSize(600,400);

  renderer.domElement.setAttribute("id", "modelobj");
  document.body.insertBefore(renderer.domElement, document.body.firstChild);

  const aLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040,1.2);
  scene.add(aLight);

  const pLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF,1.2);
  pLight.position.set(0,-4,8)
  scene.add(pLight);

  let loadder = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
  let obj = null;
  var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
  loader.load('/scene.gltf', function(gltf) {
    obj = gltf;
    obj.scene.scale.set(2, 2, 2);

    scene.add(obj.scene);
  });
```

все необходимые библиотеки подключены

Comment: - Модель большая, камера находится внутри модели. 
- Модель не попадает в поле зрения камеры.
- У модели нет нормалей - черная на черном фоне.
- Главный вопрос: где и когда вызывается `renderer.render(scene, camera);`? Возможно, стоит добавить цикл анимации, типа: `renderer.setAnimationLoop( _ => {renderer.render(scene, camera)});`

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы понять, почему модель не отображается, необходимо проанализировать конфигурацию камеры и установить, что происходит с объектом после загрузки. Попробуйте следующее:

1. Убедитесь, что путь к файлу GLTF указан правильно, вы можете
   убедится в этом, добавив console.log('Loading Model') перед строкой
   loader.load.
2. Добавьте console.log(obj) после строки obj = gltf;, чтобы убедиться,
   что объект загружен.
3. Проверьте, что параметры камеры установлены в правильные значения.
4. Вы можете также добавить функцию отладки, выводящую в консоль
   информацию о текущем состоянии сцены, вызывая console.log(scene)
   перед строкой renderer.render(scene, camera).

Если после этого ошибка не исчезла, предоставьте дополнительную информацию, чтобы я мог вам помочь.